# Error: Download a file from directory using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying  to download a file which has been stored in my HDD. Now i'm tried to use this block of code, and these code are used in button click event.
But the problem is when i'm click the button it download my form(in my case "DAO.aspx") instead of the file (SampleFile.xlsx);

```
    protected void BtnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {                
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/octect-stream";
            Response.AppendHeader("content-disp­osition", "attachment; filename=SampleFile.xlsx");
            Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/SampleExcel/SampleFile.xlsx"));
            Response.End();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {               
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You should provide more details. give us your full function and your button handler.

Comment: Details updated @AMember

Comment: You have a typo - `application/octect-stream` should be `application/octet-stream`

Comment: still it doesn't work @Lloyd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ContentType = "Application/octect-stream";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=SampleFile.xlsx");
Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath("~/SampleExcel/SampleFile.xlsx"));
```

Comment: You still need to get the 'ContentType' right though.